# unexpected error of $'do\r' for simple bash loop

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have simple bash shell, it can work under shell command, but when I execute bash

this is simple.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 2 20)
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

And when I execute

```
>bash simple.sh
simple.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
simple.sh: line 3: `do
```

what is that mean, how to change it?

Comment: Works for me with a straight copy-paste from your question; the `\r` is a carriage-return which, pending your system (I'm using cygwin on Windows) it may not like it and you'll have to update `\r\n` line endings to just `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file may end the line with `\r` instead of `\n`. Use some smart editors to show the line endings. or you can use `dos2unix` to convert the file.

Comment: Or add a semicolon before the `do`, in this way it will work whatever the line endings.

Comment: @Grapsus No, `bash` cannot handle DOS line endings, period. Writing `for ...; do` will just change the error message or push the error somewhere else. Sometimes, you don't even get an error; you just get extra carriage returns appended to parameter values.